# How do I create a column in PgAdmin4 that is based of another column

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a column that gives specific values for words in the previous column.
Example if column 1 says 'cars' I want column 2 to say 1. And if column 1 says 'trains' I want column 2 to say 2. But if column 1 doesn't say cars or trains I want column 2 to return a 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create the new column and then use a `CASE` expression to populate it with the values you want:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET new_col = CASE old_col WHEN 'cars' THEN 1
                           WHEN 'trains' THEN 2
                           ELSE 0 END;
```

In case the column `new_col` does not already exist, then create it first:

```sql
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD COLUMN new_col VARCHAR(100);
```

Comment: @akramismail You need to create the new column first.  Let me add that step to my answer above. YT

Answer (score 1):

ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN col2 VARCHAR(100);

UPDATE mytable
SET col2 = CASE col1 WHEN 'cars' THEN 1
WHEN 'trains' THEN 2
ELSE 0 END;